# handle object distance through accelerometer?

Tags: iphone

my object just follow straight line and if it is move outside the line, Its crash...When ever it is on the line then calculate distance?like increase in count variable

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can i handle distanse through accelerometer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744028/how-can-i-handle-distanse-through-accelerometer)

Comment: You just asked this same question 'http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4744028/how-can-i-handle-distanse-through-accelerometer' .. if you need more information from the people who answered, ask them in comments and such.